# I want to search streamfield in admin panel?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-search

I have about 400 different types of blocks. How can I search for them from the admin panel?

Example image:

[Example search form admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84YmK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for the block names in the default search bar. I would suggest you install wagtail-inventory and use their purpose-built search for block types:

https://github.com/cfpb/wagtail-inventory